# How to link linear progress indicator and slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am making a music player where the progress indicator will act as a slider to change the music position and also as a progress bar.
 As far as I understood the slider can only be set manually whereas the linearprogess indicator has no such slider.
 I want a way to integrate both such that the slider shows the current progress of the music track as well as the user can drag it to affect the value.

Is there any way to do so? Or if I have any misconception please correct me.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable that holds the value for the `slider` and as you slide, you update this variable and also set the variable to the progress indicator.

Like this:

```dart
class LinearSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LinearSliderState createState() => _LinearSliderState();
}

class _LinearSliderState extends State<LinearSlider> {
  double sliderValue = 0.3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Slider(
            value: sliderValue,
            onChanged: (v){
              setState(() {
                sliderValue = v;
              });
            },
          ),

          LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: sliderValue,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to show them together, not below one another. 

Comment: what do you mean by 'together'

Comment: Like on a music player. The slider shows the progress of the song updating in realtime, and when you drag the slider the music position changes. I may have some misconceptions so sorry if I asked a silly question.

Comment: @sick.sec_ I might have solution for you, but I need to know where you get the progress from? What kind of information is available to get the progress?
I've got such a solution for the Spotify api to show the progress and being able to 'drag' the pointer at a point where it starts playing from.

Comment: @ErikDohmen I am getting the progress from the length of the audio file. Like I am extracting the length in seconds and then the **(current time / total time * 100)** gives a percentage of completion of the track